# Frequencies in R using plyr

Tags: r, plyr, summarization

In my data I have a categorical variable called gender which consists of two types Male or Female. I want to obtain their counts and percentages.

For example, the data is such:

```
Gender
M
F
M
F
```

I want the output to something like:

```
Gender  Count  Percentage
M        200      50%
F        200      50%
```

I tried doing this to give me percentages but it keeps giving me an error saying, "Object female not found". Currently I have tried:

```
summarise(BirthData, "Frequencies"= count(BirthData,Gender), 
"Percent" = count(BirthData,Gender)/ sum(count(BirthData,Gender)))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think `count` cannot be used within `summarise`.  It has to be a standalone function.

Comment: `library(dplyr) ; df %>% group_by(Gender) %>% summarise(Count = n(), Percent = n()/nrow(df)*100)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `table` along with `prop.table`

```
t1 <- table(df1$Gender)
prop.table(t1)
```

Or if we need it in a `data.frame` with the specified format,

```
transform(setNames(as.data.frame(table(df1$Gender)), c("Gender", 
          "Count")), Percentage = paste0(100*Count/sum(Count), "%"))
# Gender Count Percentage
#1    F   188       47%
#2    M   212       53%
```

#### data

```
set.seed(49)
df1 <- data.frame(Gender = sample(c("M", "F"), 400, replace=TRUE), 
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: I have tried doing so, but it gives me the error:  Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables. I dont know why its saying numeric..How do I change data types?

Comment: @KonfuChicken  I updated with a working example that I used.

Comment: That worked! Thank you! How would I change the variable name of Gender though? It appears saying "Var1" above the strings Male and Female.

Comment: @KonfuChicken  We can use `setNames` (updated the post)